# Blank Page in Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, argocd

I have deployed an ingress in Kubernetes and using two applications on different ingress namespaces.

When I access the APP2 I can reach the website and it's working fine but APP1 is displaying BLANK page. No errors just BLANK and response 200 OK.

Basically I integrated ArgoCd with Azure AD. The integration it is fine but I think ingress rules are not totally fine.

Both Apps are on different namespaces so I have to use two different ingress on different namespaces:

This is the APP1:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /argo-cd/$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: argocd-server
      port:
        number: 443
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /argo-cd
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: argocd-server
              port:
                number: 443
```

And this is the APP2:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: sonarqube
      port:
        number: 9000  
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sq-example
    secretName: nginx-cert
  rules:
  - host: sq.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /sonarqube(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sonarqube
            port:
              number: 9000
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sonarqube
            port:
              number: 9000
```

args of ingress deployment:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
        - --default-ssl-certificate=ingress-nginx/ca-key-pair
        - --enable-ssl-passthrough
```

logs ingress controller pod:

```
10.200.140.160 - - [03/Nov/2021:15:00:34 +0000] "GET /argo-cd HTTP/1.1" 200 831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36" 489 0.002 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] 10.200.140.177:8080, 10.200.140.177:8080 0, 831 0.000, 0.004 502, 200 d491c01cd741fa9f155642f8616b6d9f
2021/11/03 15:09:05 [error] 867#867: *534643 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.200.140.160, server: _, request: "GET /argo-cd/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.200.140.177:8080/argo-cd/", host: "10.200.140.211"
10.200.140.160 - - [03/Nov/2021:15:09:05 +0000] "GET /argo-cd/ HTTP/1.1" 200 831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36" 440 0.006 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] 10.200.140.177:8080, 10.200.140.177:8080 0, 831 0.000, 0.004 502, 200 8995b914ae6e39d8ca781e1f4f269f50
10.200.140.160 - - [03/Nov/2021:15:09:16 +0000] "GET /argo-cd HTTP/1.1" 200 831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36" 489 0.001 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] 10.200.140.177:8080 831 0.004 200 0adadba11c87f9b88ed75d52e4ca387a
```

I tryied playing with the path: /argo-cd on APP1 like:

path: /argo-cd/
path: /argo-cd/(/|$)(.*)
path: /argo-cd/(.*)
path: /argo-cd/*

but impossible to make it work. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess: In the [argo-cd ingress docu](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#option-1-ssl-passthrough) it is written if `ssl-passthrough` is used then you have to start the nginx ingress controller with `--enable-ssl-passthrough`. Have you done this ?

Comment: @mr.wolle i added this in the ingress controller args and still getting the same.
containers:
      - args:
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --default-ssl-certificate=ingress-nginx/ca-key-pair --MORE THINGS
        - --enable-ssl-passthrough

Comment: I tested your Ingress definition with fresh [ArgoCD installation](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/manifests/install.yaml), and it's working fine. How did you install your ArgoCD and Nginx Ingress controller? Could you get name of your Ingress controller pod (`kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx`) and then run `kubectl logs {ingress-nginx-controller-pod-name} -n ingress-nginx` and paste logs?

Comment: @MikolajS. to install argoCD I followed this: 1. kubectl create namespace argocd 2. kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml 3. For AD integration I followed: Azure AD App Registration Auth using OIDC using https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/microsoft/#azure-ad-app-registration-auth-using-oidc previously I tested this in a testing installation and it was working fine but not in the staging one. Most probably it is something related to ingress controller/ingress rules... For Ingress Heml dpl

Comment: kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-77f778464b-74x6h   1/1     Running   0          12h
ingress-nginx-controller-77f778464b-wwgf2   1/1     Running   0          12h
sonarqube-774cfbc997-qj7pz                  1/1     Running   0          17h

Comment: kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-77f778464b-74x6h -n ingress-nginx 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2021:10:15:42 +0000] "GET /argo-cd HTTP/2.0" 200 831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36" 24 0.000 [argocd-argocd-server-443] [] 10.200.140.177:8080 831 0.004 200 b119947b34ee7c76ee7a09b03d4c8d91
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2021:10:15:43 +0000] "GET /argo-cd HTTP/2.0" 200 831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Comment: Also it is strange that some times when using http instead of https i get the page displayed but when login to Via Azure I get "Invalid return_url" and i am using the correct URL in AZ https:// IPargoCD/auth/callback. But I have to refresh few times to get something displayed and not working with https... the issue can be related with the certificate itself?

Comment: I can see this issue: 2021/11/03 15:09:05 [error] 867#867: *534643 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.200.140.160, server: _, request: "GET /argo-cd/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.200.140.177:8080/argo-cd/", host: "10.200.140.211"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't configure the argo-cd root path.

---

*Why?*

First, it's worth to remind that NGINX Ingress controller [by default is *Cluster-wide*](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/#running-multiple-nginx-ingress-controllers):

> - **Cluster-wide Ingress Controller (default)**. The Ingress Controller handles configuration resources created in any namespace of the cluster. As NGINX is a high-performance load balancer capable of serving many applications at the same time, this option is used by default in our installation manifests and Helm chart.

So even if you have configured Ingresses in different namespaces at the end you are using the same NGINX Ingress Controller. You can check it by running:

```
kubectl get ing -n ingress-nginx
kubectl get ing -n argocd
```

You can observe that `ADDRESS` is the same for both ingresses in different namespaces.

Let's assume that I have applied only the first ingress definition (APP1). If I try to reach `https://{ingress-ip}/argo-cd` I will be redirected to the `https://{ingress-ip}/applications` website - it works probably because you also setup the  `defaultBackend` setting. Anyway it's not a good approach - you should configure the argo-cd root path correctly.

When I applied the second ingress definition (APP2) I'm also getting the blank page as you - probably because the definitions from both ingresses are mixing and this is causing an issue.

*How to setup the argo-cd root path?*

Based on [this documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#option-2-mapping-crd-for-path-based-routing):

> Edit the `argocd-server` deployment to add the `--rootpath=/argo-cd` flag to the argocd-server command.

It's not really explained in detailed way in the docs, but I figured how to setup it:

First, we need to get current deployment configuration:

```
kubectl get deploy argocd-server -o yaml -n argocd > argocd-server-deployment.yaml
```

Now, we need to edit the `argocd-server-deployment.yaml` file. Under `command` (in my case it was line 52) we need to add `rootpath` flag - before:

```
containers:
- command:
  - argocd-server
  env:
```

After:

```
containers:
- command:
  - argocd-server
  - --rootpath=/argo-cd
  env:
```

Save it, and run `kubectl apply -f argocd-server-deployment.yaml`.

Now, it's time to edit ingress definition also - as we setup root path we need to delete `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:` annotation:

```
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

After these changes, if I reach `https://{ingress-ip}/argo-cd` I will be redirected to the `https://{ingress-ip}/argo-cd/applications`. Everything is working properly.